# Robokassa на Node JS

Tags: node.js, express, robokassa

Всем здравствуйте. Возникла проблема с Робокассой. Пользовался библиотекой [node-robokassa](https://github.com/betsol/node-robokassa). Использую в качестве сервера Express. Генерирую ссылку  и проверяю тестовую оплату для success через этот код:

```
const outSum = 52.79;
const invDesc = 'Test Transaction';

const options = {
    invId: 14893,
    isTest: true,
    userData: {
        productId: '14893',
        username: 'Mikhail'
    }
}

const paymentUrl = robokassaHelper.generatePaymentUrl(outSum, invDesc, options);
console.log(paymentUrl);

app.post('/success', (req, res) => {
    robokassaHelper.handleResultUrlRequest(req, res, (values, userData) => {
        res.send('userData')
    });
});
app.listen(3000);
```

Потом смотрю в Postman, отправляю post запрос на localhost:3000/success и вижу:

> Cannot read property 'OutSum' of undefined

Если кто-то встречался с проблемой, надеюсь на помощь. Заранее спасибо.

Comment: Просто `Cannot read property 'OutSum' of undefined`, без указания строки, позиции?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Проблема первая. Судя по этому кусочку кода, вы принимаете POST-запрос, но не обрабатываете его данные на сервере. В express это делается так:

```
const app = express();

app.use(express.urlencoded({ extended: true }));
app.use(express.json());

app.post('/success', (req, res) => { ... });
```

Потенциальная вторая проблема.

> Оповещение об оплате на ResultURL
>
> ResultURL предназначен для получения Вашим сайтом оповещения об успешном платеже в автоматическом режиме.
>
> В случае успешного проведения оплаты ROBOKASSA делает запрос на
> ResultURL (см. раздел Технические настройки) с указанием параметров
> OutSum, InvId и SignatureValue.

Перед тем как делать запрос *из Postman*, вам понадобится внимательно прочитать в документации ROBOKASSA как именно они вычисляют SignatureValue запроса (`OutSum:InvId:Пароль#2` и `100.26:450009:Пароль#2:Shp_login=Vasya:Shp_oplata=1`) и вычислить чексумму вашего запроса, иначе вы просто будете получать сообщение об ошибке:

> Incorrect signature value

Понятно, что сама ROBOKASSA обратиться к вашему `localhost` не сможет, хотя [ngrok](https://ngrok.com/) может помочь решить эту проблему.