# Не могу получить formData на nodejs серве - пустой объект

Tags: node.js, express, postman, formdata, multer

У меня есть nodejs express сервер
Сайт отправляет post c объектом formData на сервер nodejs. Смотрю результат в консоли - пустой объект.
Попробывал через postman - тоже самое

Нашел инфу про multer и попробывал его использовать,но тоже пусто (

```
const multer = require('multer')
app.post('/paymentstatus',multer().none(),(req,res) => {
  console.log(req.body)
  console.log('++++')
  res.sendStatus(200)
});

введите сюда код
```

Comment: Как с клиента отправляется запрос? Если req.body пусто, значит там ничего нет

Comment: @SwaD Пробовал использовать postman,для отправки form-data ,но тоже пусто

Comment: первая часть ответа https://ru.stackoverflow.com/a/1333149/2659

Comment: https://expressjs.com/en/4x/api.html#req.body и https://expressjs.com/en/4x/api.html#express.urlencoded