# POST http://localhost:3000/ 404 (Not Found) Не могу добавить информацию в БД

Tags: javascript, reactjs, mongodb, express, mongoose

index.js

```
const express = require('express');
const mongoose  = require('mongoose');
const Restaurant = require('./models/Restaurant');
const multer = require('multer');
const cors = require('cors');


const app = express();
const uploadMiddleware = multer();

app.use(cors({origin:'http://localhost:3000'}));
app.use(express.json());

mongoose
.connect('mongodb+srv://admin:admin@cluster0.sknl5oe.mongodb.net/?retryWrites=true&w=majority&appName=Cluster0')
.then(() => console.log('DB connected'))
.catch((err) => {
    console.error(err);
    process.exit(1);
});

app.get('/', (req, res) => {
    console.log('Это функция промежуточного программного обеспечения');
});

app.post('/',uploadMiddleware, async (req, res) => {

    const {title, description, foodType, location} = req.body;
    const postDoc = await Restaurant.create({
        title, 
        description, 
        foodType,
        location,
    })

    res.json({postDoc});
})

app.listen(3000);
```

CreateRestaurantPage.js

```
import { useState } from "react";

export default function CreateRestaurantPage() {

    const [title, setTitle] = useState('');
    const [description, setDescription]  = useState('');
    const [foodType, setFoodType] = useState('');
    const [location, setLocation] = useState('');

    async function createNewRestaurant(ev) {
        const data = new FormData();
        data.set('title', title);
        data.set('description', description);
        data.set('foodType', foodType);
        data.set('location', location )

        ev.preventDefault();
        const response = await fetch('http://localhost:3000', {
            method: 'POST',
            body: data,
        });
        if (response.ok) {
            console.log("data sent")
        }
    }

    return (
        <form onSubmit={createNewRestaurant}>
            <input 
                type="title" 
                placeholder={"Название"} 
                value={title}
                onChange={ev => setTitle(ev.target.value)}/>
            <input 
                type="description" 
                placeholder={"Описание"}
                value={description}
                onChange={ev => setDescription(ev.target.value)}/>   
            <input 
                type="foodType" 
                placeholder={"Кухня"}
                value={foodType}
                onChange={ev => setFoodType(ev.target.value)}/> 
            <input 
                type="location" 
                placeholder={"Локация"}
                value={location}
                onChange={ev => setLocation(ev.target.value)}/>   
            <button style={{marginTop: '5px'}}>Добавить ресторан</button>
        </form>
    )
}
```

Restaurant.js

```
const mongoose = require('mongoose');
const {Schema, model} = mongoose;

const RestaurantSchema = new Schema({
    title: String,
    description: String,
    foodType: String,  
    location: String,
}
);

const RestaurantModel = model('Restaurant', RestaurantSchema);
module.exports = RestaurantModel;
```

Comment: ваш index.js не запускает сервер, падает с ошибкой

Comment: что делать? чтобы заработало

Comment: когда пытаюсь запустить сервер вот что выдает 
/Users/alekseyabashkin/node_modules/express/lib/router/route.js:211
        throw new Error(msg);
        ^

Error: Route.post() requires a callback function but got a [object Object]
    at Route.<computed> [as post] (/Users/alekseyabashkin/node_modules/express/lib/router/route.js:211:15)
    at app.<computed> [as post]

Comment: @nörbörnën что делать

Comment: а что вы прочитали в сообщении об ошибке?

Comment: я убрал пару строк которые похоже ничего не делали и оставил так
app.get('/', (req, res) => {});

app.post('/', async (req, res) => {

    const {title, description, foodType, location} = req.body;
    const RestaurantDoc = await Restaurant.create({
        title, 
        description, 
        foodType,
        location,
    })

    res.json({RestaurantDoc});
})

Comment: теперь пост запросы проходят в mongodb появляются новые элементы в нужной коллекции, но проблема в том что они пустые

Comment: вот что появляется в дб {"_id":{"$oid":"65e1e8763a3167302f734edf"},"__v":{"$numberInt":"0"}}

Comment: хотя у меня иодель для отправки пост запроса с полями

Comment: @nörbörnën как считаете что может быть проблемой

Comment: и еще при отправки на mongo db в консоли вот такое
WebSocketClient.js:13 WebSocket connection to 'ws://localhost:3000/ws' failed:

Comment: думаю, нехватает заклинания express.urlencoded. тут пример https://ru.stackoverflow.com/a/1333149/2659, тут дока https://expressjs.com/en/api.html#express.urlencoded

Comment: @nörbörnën не помогло, все еще пустой объект в бд

Comment: я нашел ошибку, дело в том что я неправильно записывал данные в модель и отправлял сам по сути ничего, извините за потраченное время